# How to upscale 500px x 500px to 20k px x 20k px?

Tags: stable-diffusion

I have many low resolution images around 500px, and I want to upscale them to 20k px x 20k px. (Basically, I want to print 300 DPI on 2 meter x 2 meter post).

I tried to use "extra" in automatic111 WebUI for stable diffusion. The best I can get is 8x the original one.

I also tried to use "script" in image2image, but it struggles to fit my memory for 8x.

Is it possible to do a 500px upscaling?

I have attached a sample image. Note that this one is around 1000 x 300 px.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One can use Topaz Gigapixel's Image Upscaler to upscale images up to [600%](https://www.topazlabs.com/gigapixel-upscale-ai-generated-art#:%7E:text=Gigapixel%20AI%20uses%20sophisticated%20machine,artwork%20for%20print%20and%20merchandise.). So it won't output all the way to 20k px x 20k px in your case, but still can be very helpful. I've used Topaz Gigapixel 6, upscaling works great on some images.